# extract all possible combinations from a and or clause

Tags: python, combinations

Given is a list with possible combinations (|| is or, && is and).

`lst = ['(a || b) && (c && d)', '(e && f) || (g || h)', '(i || j) || k']`

How can i get all possible combinations out of this in a new list?
Result of the sample would be:

```
rsltlst = ['a && c && d', 'b && c && d',  'e && f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
```

Thanks!

to reduce complexity instead of the list it can also be a single string:

```
str = '(a || b) && (c && d)'
```

that would give you 2 solutions:

```
sol1 = 'a && c && d'
sol2 = 'b && c && d'
```

Comment: are you looking for a general approach, or for this case (specifically, formatting) in particular?

Comment: actually specific as the given data uses this symbols for bracket, AND and OR. If it is general i would try to apply.

Comment: and the individual items in the list - the assumption is there is also `||` between them?
that is
`lst = ['(a || b) && (c && d)', '(e && f) || (g || h)', (i || j) || k')`
is the same as
`lst = ['((a || b) && (c && d)) || ((e && f) || (g || h)) || ((i || j) || k)']`?

Comment: no this is just for post processing so it doesn't matter as long as there is a diffrence between AND and OR. Can be string as well.

Comment: if i get you right, you just want to 'expand' the logical expressions (show all specific allowed combinations)? So this is just a string evaluation problem equivalent to evaluate mathematical expressions from strings. For the latter, you would reformat the expression to the polish notation and then it's straightforward. For this problem, i would suggest you to expand each braket step by step. So (a||b)&&(c&&d) -> a &&(c&&d) || b&&(c&&d). It's a little bit of work, but not that hard since the rules are clearly defined.

Comment: @Florian: that was my initial idea but i have no idea how to read that in proberly to follow it mathematically correct. As example the first set of data ended up as: 'a', 'b AND 'c' AND 'd'

Comment: Please, specify more precisely the output and the input. Is there an implicit "or" between elements of the list? Why `a&&b&&c&&d` is not among the combinations? (if it were logic simplification,  I would get that it is already implied by `a&&b&&c`. But then, that is also implied by `a&&c`. So, why `a&&b&&c` and not `a&&c` or `a&&b&&c&&d`? And why not `a&&c&&i`?

Comment: Besides, it would be could to have an example that is at least syntaxically correct (if I cut&paste your code in my python, I get a syntax error. Would be nice to have only code that you've tried yourself)

Comment: @chrslg: Syntax corrected, missing bracket. a&&b&&c&&d is no valid solution because it can be a or b not both

Comment: No. Just try it, please. It is invalid.

Comment: @himself So it is a mutually exclusive or? A XOR? That is not what `||` means usually. And why not `a&&c&&d&&i`?

Comment: Yes mutually exclusive is the correct expression. The context is shown like this in the input data. every item of the list is it's own content. they do not interact.

Comment: Ok (there is still an extra parenthesis in your expression. It would be good if you could validate that it works on your own python). But mutually exclusive or is not named `or` nor `||`. It is a `xor`, noted `^`. So if I get it correctly, for each expression in `lst`, you need ALL possible combinations of symbols that match the expression. And your would never use any real "OR". There are only exclusive or and and it the expressions?

Comment: you are right. if you have only AND the '()' are not necessary. Unfortunatly this is how the input comes

Comment: My feeling is that, it is not really "XOR" but "OR". But what you are looking for are not list of combinations, but DNF form of your expressions. The DNF form (well, DN form. The F already stands for "Form"), of a logical expression never combine two things that are related by OR. Not because it is forbiden. But because it is not necessary. I was about to post a very very similar answer as the one from Tranbi (with the same `sympy`, `to_dnf`, `replace('||','|')`...) Only I was about to use the ugly `eval` when they used `parse_expr`. So their answer is better.

Comment: But I wanted to be sure before that, that we were talking DNF, not list of combinations (it may not be the same if some sub-expressions simplify to `True` for example). But, well, I think you got the correct answer, since 2 independent people came out with the same. It would be interesting to validate with other examples on your side, since it is still not 100% clear that this is what you expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sympy. It will help you to:

- parse your expressions with [parse_expr](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr)
- convert the expressions to disjunctive normal form with [to_dnf](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#sympy.logic.boolalg.to_dnf)

Then just split along `|`:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.logic.boolalg import to_dnf

lst = ['(a || b) && (c && d)', '(e && f) || (g || h)', '(i || j) || k']
lst = map(lambda x: x.replace('||', '|').replace('&&', '&'), lst)

comb = set()

for exp in lst:
    log_expr = str(to_dnf(parse_expr(exp)))
    for e in log_expr.split('|'):
        comb.add(str(parse_expr(e)))

print(comb)
```

Output:

```
{'a & c & d', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'b & c & d', 'e & f', 'k', 'j'}
```

Edit: replacing `e.strip()` with `str(parse_expr(e))` to avoid duplicates due to parenthesis